# Java String from InputStream

Tags: java, stream

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I convert an InputStream to a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763789/how-do-i-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string-in-java)
>   [In Java how do a read an input stream in to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-an-input-stream-in-to-a-string)

I have an `InputSteam` and need to simply get a single simple `String` with the complete contents.

How is this done in Java?

Comment: Can you elaborate? By definition, a Stream is unbounded. Unless there are some more constraints, you can't get a String (something of fixed size) from an unbounded stream.

Comment: This has been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763789/how-do-i-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-an-input-stream-in-to-a-string

Comment: How to do it with nio FileChannel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390

Comment: Awesome solution here: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/383414)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a modification of Gopi's answer that doesn't have the line ending problem and is also more effective as it doesn't need temporary String objects for every line and avoids the redundant copying in BufferedReader and the extra work in readLine().

```
public static String convertStreamToString( InputStream is, String ecoding ) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( Math.max( 16, is.available() ) );
    char[] tmp = new char[ 4096 ];

    try {
       InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( is, ecoding );
       for( int cnt; ( cnt = reader.read( tmp ) ) > 0; )
            sb.append( tmp, 0, cnt );
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 more sane encoding handling.

Answer (score 6):

You need to construct an `InputStreamReader` to wrap the input stream, converting between binary data and text. Specify the appropriate encoding based on your input source.

Once you've got an `InputStreamReader`, you could create a `BufferedReader` and read the contents line by line, or just read buffer-by-buffer and append to a `StringBuilder` until the `read()` call returns -1.

The [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) library makes the second part of this easy - use [`CharStreams.toString(inputStreamReader)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html).

Comment: I've never tried this, but shouldn't you be aware of what the stream represents before you do this? If you were to have a stream such that read() would never return -1, there would be no value in even trying this. But, at the same time, I can't think of a stream off the top of my head that never ends.

Comment: @Thomas: Well, you could easily create a stream which only ever gave random numbers. I was assuming that the question was asked in a situation where the concept of "read to the end of the stream" did actually make sense...

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example code adapted from [here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html).

```
public  String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        if (is != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            try {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } else {       
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that that will normalize line endings - it won't necessarily return the exact original text data.

Comment: true. edited code to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Now it won't include the line endings at all.  I think Jon Skeet was just saying that every line ending `\r\n` (or `\r`) becomes `\n`.

Comment: aaah. thanks for bringing it to notice. reverted.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/io)

Specifically, you can use [IOUtils#toString(InputStream inputStream) method](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: As a software engineer, I love this. Reusing existing libraries to get the job done. Apache Commons (and all of the Apache projects in general) are very well done and quite helpful in a number of situations.

Comment: Note that using the method above uses the platforms default encoding, i.e. the result depends on user settings or other external factors. Most of the time it is better to use a method expecting the encoding as additional parameter. See [this comment on a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string#comment4886900_309448). Apaches `IOUtils` provides such methods, too. BTW, the link to Javadoc is broken…

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a [StringWriter](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) as follows; each `read` from your InputStream is matched with a `write` (or `append`) to the StringWriter, and upon completion you can call `getBuffer` to get a StringBuffer which could be used directly or you could get call its `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Stream in a Reader to get locale conversion, and then keep reading while collecting in a StringBuffer.  When done, do a toString() on the StringBuffer.